# get the next row data on click of the current row using fnGetPosition in jquery datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

Datatables jquery plugin's fnGetPosition function is being used to fetch the row position. Using this i want to know if the next row has data or not based on the row position i have got.

```
var rowPosition = dataTable.fnGetPosition(this)[0];
```

The above code returns me the row number. I want to get the row number of the next visible row based on the above code. Can i do something like:

```
(dataTable.fnGetPosition(this)[0]) + 1
```

which returns the next row number?

Comment: `fnGetPosition` returns an `int` so you should be able to do that - what happens if you try?

Comment: i click on a row and fnGetPosition returns me the required int row position. But i want to know the next row position based on that clicked row.

Comment: so just add 1 to it as you suggested, or do `var nextRow = rowPosition + 1`

Comment: so if row position is 2 for example, adding +1 would be 3. ok thats correct. what if i do a search on the datatable and the result rows have different row position. doing +1 would be incorrect.

Comment: but if you click on a row again, it would get the new value from fnGetPosition, and you can do +1 then. Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do, soz if that's the case.

Comment: ok. i need the position to check for the row data.i also want to know if the next row contains data. so if i click on a row, then i want the data of that particular row and also the next row. for this reason i do a fnGetPosition to get the position of it and fetch the details using fnGetNodes. doing +1 is fine for me if i do not do any search filter on it. but it will return me wrong data if i do + 1 on the searched data.

Comment: ok I get it now. Have you tried [fnGetData](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnGetData)? You should be able to call `fnGetData` on the current clicked row, which will return the row and you then use jquery `.next()` to get the next row.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is extremely old but I recently came across this problem when working with the latest version of Datatables (Sept 2019). I was extremely surprised (shocked!) to see that not only has the fnGetData function be removed but there  seemingly is not a next() function whatsoever for moving down to the next visible row of a Datatables table. There isn't even a forum post that deals with this. Fortunately, JQuery is there and I was able to devise a simple strategy for moving down to the next row regardless of sort order.

First, capture the event target if for whatever event is triggering your code. For me, I was catching the keypress event on one of the cells in the row. The event target (evt.target) is an INPUT element in my case. Then, go up the DOM with a couple of parentElement references until you find the TR element. This is your Datatable row. Now, check for the existence of nextSibling. If one exists, this is the next row and you can use a JQuery selector to find (in my case) an INPUT element with the same class on it so it can be activated. Here's what it looks like for me (I'm using a simple CellEdit plug-in for Datatables):

```
$('.cell-can-edit').on('keypress', function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    var pr = e.target.parentElement.parentElement; //row containing the active cell
    var ns = pr.nextSibling; //next row down
    if (ns) {
      $('td.cell-can-edit', ns).click();  //activate the next row
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: So you actually can do this with the API

    `var tableIndexes = table.rows({ filter: 'applied' }).indexes();`
    `var curRowIndex = tableIndexes.indexOf(row);`
    `var nextRow =  tableIndexes[curRowIndex + 1];`